# Access-Control-Allow-Origin even on same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

In chrome dev tools I get the error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com/xmls/carcraft_1-7-10Test.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com' is therefore not allowed access."

Why am I getting this error when the files are both on the same domain?

In case you need it here is the applicable code:
XML (page will be blank right click and view source):
https://carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com/xmls/carcraft_1-7-10Test.xml

Section of HTML page it being put into:

```
                <article>
                    <header>

                    </header>

                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <table id="ModsList">
                        <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
                        <td>Mod Name</td>
                        <td>Author(s)</td>
                        <td>Version</td>
                        <td>Date added/updated</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>

                    <script src="https://www.code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="/test.js"></script>
                </article>
```

And here is the javascript/jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com/xmls/carcraft_1-7-10Test.xml',
    type: "Get",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (result) {
        $(result).find('Module').each(function() {
             var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var url = $(this).find('url').text();
            var authors = $(this).find('authors').text();
            var version = $(this).find('version').text();
            var date = $(this).find('date').text();
            var description = $(this).find('description').text();
            $("#ModsList").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=" + url + ">" + name + "</a>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + authors + "</td>" + "<td>" + version + "</td>" + "<td>" + date + "</td>" + "<td>" + description + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        });
    },
    failure: function() {
    alert("Notify the site owner that the xml file is unreadable.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not [the same domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules). Same-origin policy requires an *exact match* for domains. One url has `www.` which is essentially makes it a different domain regardles if it serves the same exact site. Remove the `www` from the url your AJAX call uses.

```
https://www.carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com
https://carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com
```

Comment: Wow, I feel so dumb for missing that. Thank you! Will mark as accepted after timer allows me too.